# iOS: Continuos waiting on flag till location updated

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, volatile

I am trying to get the current location whenever required and stop updating locations immediately. For this I wrote following code but continuos waiting on volatile flag doen't seem to working. It doesn't fire location updates evens when I am waiting on the flag. Could someone please tell me what's wrong in my code. Thanks.

```
CurrentLocation.h file:

@property (nonatomic, assign) volatile BOOL locationUpdatedFlag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

CurrentLocation.m file:

@synthesize currentLocation = _currentLocation;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;
@synthesize locationUpdatedFlag = _locationUpdatedFlag;

- (void)xxx
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.locationUpdatedFlag = NO;

    while(!self.locationUpdatedFlag)
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.1];

    // Use self.currentLocation

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    self.locationUpdatedFlag = YES;
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    NSLog(@"Error from Location Manager");
    self.locationUpdatedFlag = YES;
}
```

Comment: The delegate methods are fired in the same thread which started the location manager meaning you are blocking them with `sleepForTimeInterval`.

Comment: I thought of this but is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: The common way would be to remove the `while(){sleep}` part and move the `// Use self.currentLocation` operations into the separate method called from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` after you stop the manager. That is the most natural use of the delegate and you'll want to use it. Other than that there are plenty of other solutions like adding observer to `locationUpdatedFlag` keypath or creating a `separate` thread manually to wait for it sleeping like you did.

Comment: Thanks @A-Live could you please put this as an answer. I will accept it. I do stuffs in delegate directly but I was thinking of creating class that returns me current location whenever I need! KVO would be great idea here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to fix this would be to remove the `while(){sleep}` part and move the `// Use self.currentLocation operations` into the separate method called from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` after you stop the manager. That is the most natural use of the delegate and you'll want to use it. Other than that there are plenty of other solutions like adding observer to `locationUpdatedFlag` keypath or creating a `separate` thread manually to wait for it sleeping like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You have that delegate callback for a reason... So you don't have to lock the thread polling for if something's finished. Change the design of your class so that you don't do that anymore. I bet it will fix your problem and you will have a  better user experience.